# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table doesn't exist

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

When I access it at http://localhost:8080/api/projects, I guess that it connects to my MySQL database, where I have a table PROJECTS(ID, TITLE), but shows following error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'bugtrackerdb.projects' doesn't exist
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECTS")
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public class Project implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "TITLE")
private String title;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Module> modules;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Bug> bugs;
```

Resource

```
@Component
@Path("/projects")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ProjectsResource {

    @Autowired
    ProjectService projectService;

    @GET
    public List<Project> getProjects() {
        return projectService.getAllProjects();
    }

    @POST
    public Project createProject(Project project) {
        return projectService.createProject(project);
    }
}
```

Repository

```
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Long> {

}
```

Hibernate properties

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.show_sql=true
entitymanager.packages.to.scan=intuitio.kickstart.jersey.domain
hibernate.auto=create
```

Connection properties

```
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/bugtrackerdb
db.username=root
db.password=pass
```

Comment: run "show tables" on database "bugtrackerdb" and post it here

Comment: @premkumar 
    'BUGS'
    'COMMENTS'
    'MODULES'
    'PROJECTS'
    'USERS'

Comment: can you post the datasource connection properties? connection properties

Comment: @premkumar added it to the bottom of the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` not `hibernate.auto` to create a database.

Comment: Thank you for answer. In fact I have an ApplicationConfig class where I set dataSource and hibernate properties extracted from a *.properties file and I didn't write "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" properly in that class.

Comment: @NicolaeFocsa You are welcome. You can refer [HibernateSessionFactory.Builder](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/factory/HibernateSessionFactory.java#L128) as an example of configuration utility class.

Comment: @v.ladynev im using **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto** and still got the same error ! :3

Comment: @FuSsA Please, ask your own question and provide your configuration.

Comment: @v.ladynev [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927420/table-doesnt-existcom-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlsyntaxerrorexception)