# Table doesn't exist:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, wildfly

**Entity 1:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "META_INF")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class META_INF {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean aa;

    @ManyToOne
    private USER bb;

    @NotBlank
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    private USER cc;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean dd;

    private String ee;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean ff;

    @NotBlank
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "tt")
    @ManyToOne
    private AZE tt;


}
```

**Entity 2:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "QWE", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "a", "b", "c", "d" }) })
public class QWE extends META_INF {

    @NotBlank
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "a")
    @ManyToOne
    private PIL_P_TRATMNT a;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "b")
    private String b;

    @NotBlank
    @Min(value = 0)
    @Digits(integer = 3, fraction = 0)
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "c")
    private int c;

    @NotBlank
    @Min(value = 0)
    @Digits(integer = 3, fraction = 0)
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "d")
    private int d;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "e")
    private String e;

    @Column(name = "f")
    private String f;


    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "g")
    private String g;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "h")
    private String h;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "i")
    private String i;

    @Digits(integer = 2, fraction = 0)
    @Column(name = "j")
    private int j;

    public QWE () {
    }   

}
```

and lot of other entities..

**application.properties** to specify the credentials to access to the database:

```
jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/transverse
jdbc.username = root
jdbc.password = root
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

the database is empty. when I try to run the SpringMVC app, it gives me this error **( tables are created in DB )**:

```
WARN : org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl - GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Unable to execute command [
    alter table QWE 
        drop 
        foreign key FK5f4s5qg3vma47jthit51i7wvy]
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Unable to execute command [
    alter table QWE 
        drop 
        foreign key FK5f4s5qg3vma47jthit51i7wvy]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:370)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:198)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'transverse.qwe' doesn't exist
```

i got the same error for all other entities

Comment: It looks like your table name 'QWE' but somehow your ORM code is mapped to Table 'transverse.qwe'. If you see the error says Table `'transverse.qwe' doesn't exist`.

Comment: @SureshKoya.. i will got the same error even if i change the tbale name to 'qwe' in my entity

Comment: Since it appears for all entities, it almost seems like you don't have permissions in the database to create/update/anything, even though I see you're logged in as root

Comment: @ScottSosna i have permissions in the database ..i have tried the same configuration with an entity without constraint or Inheritance and it worked

Comment: would have been nice to have mentioned that, you said that all entities were failing, not just the contrained/inherited ones.

Comment: @ScottSosna yes all entities were failing..the one that worked was on another app that i created just for test

Comment: Which version of Hibernate?  FYI: There were some recent change to the schema tooling.  Does your app stop working after this exception or does it actually work once it has completed initialization?

Comment: @Naros hibernate5.1.0Final..even with this errors the tables are created on the DB..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned:

> the database is empty. when I try to run the SpringMVC app, it gives me this error.

It is expected that you get this error when the database is empty. Here is what will happen when you specify hbm2ddl.auto=create.

```
 --Execute the scripts in this order
 alter table <TABLE NAME> drop foreign key <CONSTRAINT NAME>;

 drop table <TABLE NAME> if exists

 create table <TABLE NAME>

 alter table <TABLE NAME> add constraint <CONSTRAINT NAME>
```

When hibernate runs the scripts with these settings the very first time, the errors which are detected since the constriants are missing will be logged as **warnings**. The DROP scripts will not fail since they have the if exists check.

On a second run the constraints will exist and the `alter table drop constraint` statements will not fail. Hence you will not see any errors.

Comment: not necessary , hibernate can handle that with that property : **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create**

Comment: to give u an exemple that the empty database is not the reason: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36823935/jdbc4-mysqlsyntaxerrorexception-table-doesnt-exist-in-database?noredirect=1#comment61382676_36823935)..

Comment: Can you post the question with the SQL generated by hbm. Do you get the error after multiple restarts? Please update your question with this details?

Comment: i shared the code i have on my console ..the same error is shown for each table..as i said my DB is empty and when i run my app..the tables are created and the **Table doesn't exist:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException** error is shown

Comment: This has nothing to do with setting `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` as `update`.  This is because the semantics around using `create` changed.

Comment: @SureshKoya i confirm that the errors are catched when trying to drop constraint first time on an empty DB..

Comment: I'd love to know why this happens. Surely "create" should mean "assume the database is empty and create the tables, not try to drop any foreign key constraints assuming the tables exist". Just spent an hour pulling my hair out trying to find out why this is happening and I find it's meant to happen. Backwards! As someone just getting into this, I couldn't find documentation on this anywhere. Very annoying. +1, thanks for explaining this.